# ModelMatrix + ViewMatrix vs ModelViewMatrix

Tags: opengl, 3d, shader, matrix-multiplication

I have a code that works passing the modelViewMatrix to the shader. I try to pass the modelMatrix and the viewMatrix separatly, but I don't get the same result, and I really don't understand what I am missing...

Here are some part of my code :

- ***Passing the ModelViewmatrix (working fine)***

**java code :**

```
        shaderProgram.loadProjectionMatrix(renderer.getProjectionMatrix());

        Matrix4f viewMatrix = TransformationMatrix.createViewMatrix(renderer.camera);
        Matrix4f modelMatrix = new Matrix4f();
        modelMatrix.setIdentity();

        Matrix4f layerTransformationMatrix = getTransformationMatrix();
        // set the translation
        Vector3f entityTranslation = shaderProgram.getTranslation();
        modelMatrix.m30 = entityTranslation.x;
        modelMatrix.m31 = entityTranslation.y;
        modelMatrix.m32 = entityTranslation.z;

        // mix the modelMatrix with the layer transformation
        modelMatrix.mul(layerTransformationMatrix);

        // reset the rotation
        modelMatrix.m00 = viewMatrix.m00;
        modelMatrix.m01 = viewMatrix.m10;
        modelMatrix.m02 = viewMatrix.m20;
        modelMatrix.m10 = viewMatrix.m01;
        modelMatrix.m11 = viewMatrix.m11;
        modelMatrix.m12 = viewMatrix.m21;
        modelMatrix.m20 = viewMatrix.m02;
        modelMatrix.m21 = viewMatrix.m12;
        modelMatrix.m22 = viewMatrix.m22;

        // compute modelViewMatrix
        Matrix4f modelViewMatrix = modelMatrix;
        modelViewMatrix.mul(viewMatrix);
        // inverse y axis
        modelViewMatrix.m11 = -1;

        shaderProgram.loadModelViewMatrix(modelViewMatrix);
```

**shader code :**

```
    void main(void)
    {
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(attribute_Position.xy, 0.0, 1.0);

        pass_textureCoords = attribute_TextureCoords;
        varying_Color = attribute_Color;
    }
```

**Screenshot :**

[image]

- ***Passing the ModelMatrix and the ViewMatrix (not working)***

**java code :**

```
        shaderProgram.loadProjectionMatrix(renderer.getProjectionMatrix());

        Matrix4f viewMatrix = TransformationMatrix.createViewMatrix(renderer.camera);
        Matrix4f modelMatrix = new Matrix4f();
        modelMatrix.setIdentity();

        Matrix4f layerTransformationMatrix = getTransformationMatrix();
        // set the translation
        Vector3f entityTranslation = shaderProgram.getTranslation();
        modelMatrix.m30 = entityTranslation.x;
        modelMatrix.m31 = entityTranslation.y;
        modelMatrix.m32 = entityTranslation.z;

        // mix the modelMatrix with the layer transformation
        modelMatrix.mul(layerTransformationMatrix);

        // reset the rotation
        modelMatrix.m00 = viewMatrix.m00;
        modelMatrix.m01 = viewMatrix.m10;
        modelMatrix.m02 = viewMatrix.m20;
        modelMatrix.m10 = viewMatrix.m01;
        modelMatrix.m11 = viewMatrix.m11;
        modelMatrix.m12 = viewMatrix.m21;
        modelMatrix.m20 = viewMatrix.m02;
        modelMatrix.m21 = viewMatrix.m12;
        modelMatrix.m22 = viewMatrix.m22;

        shaderProgram.loadModelMatrix(modelMatrix);
        shaderProgram.loadViewMatrix(viewMatrix);
```

**shader code :**

```
void main(void)
{
    mat4 MVMatrix = modelMatrix * viewMatrix;
    MVMatrix[1][1] = -1;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * MVMatrix * vec4(attribute_Position.xy, 0.0, 1.0);

    pass_textureCoords = attribute_TextureCoords;
    varying_Color = attribute_Color;
}
```

**Screenshot :**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order in which you multiply the matrices in the shader is wrong. It has to be

```
mat4 MVMatrix = viewMatrix * modelMatrix;
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33958379/opengl-transform-matrix-order-is-backwards/33958564#33958564) for an explanation.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. Good explanations !